# Recovery Models for SQL Anywhere

Tags: sqlanywhere, recoverymodel

What is the equivalent to Simple/Full Recovery mode in SQL Anywhere?  How do I switch between the recovery models?  I have a database that I would like to change to simple recovery mode during an upgrade, so that the log file doesn't blow up, flood our write cache, etc.

I have tried looking all over for this, but maybe I'm using the wrong wording, and recovery models don't exist in SQL Anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is such a concept in SQL Anywhere.

You may want to ask your question at http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/, a Q&A site specifically for SQL Anywhere.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*